# SQL syntax error on constraints

Tags: sql

Constraints and table not right, not sure where. Red lines under first constraints line and vehicle_code in SQL script:

```
create table hires (
    vehicle_code_id varchar(25) primary key,
    customer_id int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    hired_from_date datetime not null,
    hired_to_date datetime not null,
    bond smallmoney not null,

    constraint hires_pk primary key (hired_from_date),
    constraint vehicle_code_fk foreign key (vehicle_code) references hires (vehicle_code_id),
    constraint customer_fk foreign Key (customer_id) references customers (customer_id),
    constraint employee_fk foreign key (employee_id) references employees (employee_id)
)
```

Comment: You cannot have two primary key constraints.

Comment: Also, `vehicle_code_fk` - I'm not sure what you were trying to do there. It appears to be a self-referencing constraint but it names a non-existent column as the reference and the only obvious replacement would make it literally a foreign key to itself.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is a query language, not a database product.